# how to know if mouse click was done on title bar

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have a panel component on my flex application. This component has a click event which is fired when the used makes click on the panel. But I would like to know the zone of the panel where click was made. In fact what I want to know is if click was made on the title bar of the panel.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [MouseEvent](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html) stores the location of the mouse when the click was made in the `localX` and `localY` properties. That way you can calculate a bit to find out, if the mouse was above the title bar or not.

```
function panelClick ( event:MouseEvent ) : void
{
    trace( event.localX + '/' + event.localY );
}
```

Most standard components also offer access to some of their child elements. The Panel component for example has a property [Panel.titleBar](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/3/langref/mx/containers/Panel.html#titleBar) that can be accessed when deriving a new component class. So you could for example create a new class that offers a special event for clicks on the title bar, by making it possible to add an event listener for the title bar from the outside.

Comment: Thank you! Finally I created a custom component extending Panel class and added a function that returns the titleBar property to get its width and height.